# Fork(): Dont return from child until it's terminated

Tags: c++, linux, fork, invocation

I'm having some troubles with fork() and that kind of things.

I'm developing a shell, where the user can write commands that whill be executed as in a normal and common shell.

I have a main function like this:

```
void Shell::init() {
    string command;
    while (1) {
        cout << getPrompt() << " ";
        command = readCommand();
        if (command.length() > 0) handleCommand(command);
    }
}
```

`handleCommand()` is the function that does pretty much everything. Somewhere in it, I have the following:

```
...
else {
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();

    char* arg[tokens.size() + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); ++i) {
        arg[i] = (char*) tokens[i].c_str();
    }
    arg[tokens.size()] = NULL;

    if (pid == 0) {
        if (execvp(tokens[0].c_str(), arg) == -1) {
            cout << "Command not known. " << endl;
        };
    } else {
        wait();
    }
}
```

What I want is that when I reach that point, the command will be treated as a program invocation, so I create a child to run it. It's working almost perfect, but I get the prompt again before the program output. Example:

```
tronfi@orion:~/NetBeansProjects/Shell2$ whoami
tronfi@orion:~/NetBeansProjects/Shell2$ tronfi

tronfi@orion:~/NetBeansProjects/Shell2$
```

The child should die after the `execvp`, so it shouldn't be calling the prompt, and the parent is waiting until the child die.

So... what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: I don't think this is precisely your problem, but consider what happens if `execvp()` fails. How many instances of your shell would you have at that point?

Comment: I think the title of this question is going to trigger my mid-life crisis...

Comment: Ok Greg, I suppouse that I should have to kill the child from the parent. Am I wrong?

Comment: You're right David, I just changed it, hehe

Comment: +1 to Greg: For debugging, I'd add the shell pid to the prompt; and also print the pid of newly created child processes.

Comment: I've expanded on my comment in an answer with code.

Comment: What version of wait are you using that does not look correct. http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait Also I would wait for a particular child to die rather than waiting for a generic child (or signal).

Comment: move your if ( pid == 0 ) up to include your argument string setup code. There's no point doing that code in both the parent and the child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `wait()` incorrectly.  It expects to be passed a pointer-to-int, in which the child's exit status will be stored:

```
int status;
wait(&status);
```

Really, though, you should be using `waitpid()` to check for the specific child that you're after.  You also need to loop around if `waitpid()` is interrupted by a signal:

```
int r;
do {
    r = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
} while (r < 0 && errno == EINTR);
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much. This is working perfect right now. 

What I dont understand is how the parent know wich is the PID of the child, because that "pid" should be the pid of the child, right? And I enter in "child mode" when pid==0...

I hope you understand my question!

Comment: @Tronfi: Yes, that's the PID of the child - the parent knows it because it's the value returned by `fork()`, which is stored in the variable `pid` in your example.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that this is exactly the problem, but you must ensure that the child exits even if `execvp()` fails:

```
if (pid == 0) {
    if (execvp(tokens[0].c_str(), arg) == -1) {
        cout << "Command not known. " << endl;
    };
    exit(1); // or some other error code to indicate execvp() fails
} else {
    wait();
}
```

If you don't do this, then if `excecvp()` fails then you will end up with *two* instances of your shell, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks Greg, you're right. But this doesn't solve my problem ><

Answer (score 0):

The child must be terminated using the call

```
exit(0)
```

(only on success), as this helps in clening of memory and flushes the buffer. This status returned by the child must be checked by the parent and then only it should give the prompt.

Let me know if you need more details.